# Why I can not receive results of axios in ReactJs Datatables in render section

Tags: reactjs, datatables, axios

Good Day, I can receive the results of my simple object state variable "var blogs" in My datatables plugin in render section of my component, But if I try to change the variable in datatable in render section to variable that I get from axios "var blogs_ajax" I can not see the results of datatable action on my screen
That is my code, Please help me Sorry I can not put this code in action snippet because of including Datatables library

```
export default class AllBlogs extends Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        blogs: [
            {
                "title":"функция Query — подробное руководство",
                "author":1,
                "viewers":213
            },
            {
                "title":"функция Query — подробное руководство",
                "author":1,
                "viewers":213
            }
        ],
        blogs_ajax:[]
    };

    this.navItems();
}


componentDidMount() {
}

async navItems() {
    await axios
        .post("http://localhost:8000/api/blogs/getAllBlogs/")
        .then(response => {
                //console.log(response);

                return response;
            }
        )
        .then(json => {
        console.log(json.data.data)
            if (json.data.success) {

                this.setState(() => ({blogs_ajax: json.data.data.aaData}))
            } else alert("Blogs Failed!");

        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert(`An Error Occured! ${error}`);

        });
}

render() {
    const {blogs_ajax} = this.state;
    console.log(this.state.blogs_ajax) // But I can see the result here


    return (

        <div id="content" className="animated fadeInUp">
            <WidgetGrid>
                <div className="row">
                    <article className="col-sm-12">
                        <JarvisWidget id="wid-id-0" editbutton={false} color="darken">
                            <header>
                          <span className="widget-icon">
                            <i className="fa fa-table"/>
                          </span>
                            <h2></h2>
                            </header>

                            <div>
                                <div className="widget-body no-padding">

                                    <Datatable

                                          options={{
                                           data: this.state.blogs_ajax , 
          // But I can not receive array of objects here from axios
                                           columns: [
                                                {data: "title"},
                                                {data: "author"},
                                                {data: "viewers"},
                                         ]
                                        }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your render section is going first and you didnt get your axios result.Try to go this way check if results already presents

```
${this.state.postBlog.status ?
<Datatable
options={{
columns: [
{data: "title"},
{data: "author"},
{data: "viewers"},
]
}}

paginationLength={true}
className="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
width="100%"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your state contains two properties, blogs and blogs_ajax.

In your render method, you create a const from the state, but this contains two objects, not the array of objects.

To me it looks like you have a small hard-coded list whilst getting your table working, but now it is you want to display the array in this.state.blogs_ajax.

Change the constant to this.state.blogs_ajax, or even better delete the constant and in the data tables Options object, just assign this.state.blogs_ajax.  For clarity, datatables is expecting an array of objects, not an object.

Comment: Please provide me with your code It is to hard to understand, But I think I had trying that you say

Comment: I even change my task as you saying, but without profit

Comment: I can try and help, but I don’t have a code example to give you.  Can you give me a link to the data table you’re using?  Or at least the require/import command you’re using.  There’s lots of datatables out there so I’m not sure which you have.  I think you are close to fixing this.  Have you tried putting curly brackets around the data assignment?  E.g data: {this.state.blogs_ajax}

Comment: If you can tell me the github repo or npm name for the datatable, I can try a build an example later.

Comment: https://github.com/imediasun/lara_react  /src/views/all-projects/components/AllBlogs.js

Comment: Thanks for your attempts to help me

Comment: As you can see http://prntscr.com/n04tx4 I can receive in console.log(this.state.blogs_ajax) array of objects in render section of component But in datatables it is missing

Answer (score 0):

OK, this issue was not how you're passing in the data now.  It is more to do with how you're handling the data updates in your datatables.net wrapper.

I've used datatables quite a bit in Javascript and within React, but I've never seen the table instatiated in that way.

When the data does finally load, you need to check when or not to update the component.  Saying true in shouldComponentUpdate usually does the trick, but not in the way you create the table.

I've two examples below.

Play.js

```
import Datatable from '../components/datatable';
import React from "react";

export default class AllBlogs extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        blogs: [
            {
              "title":"функция Query — подробное руководство",
              "author":1,
              "viewers":213
            },
            {
              "title":"функция Query — подробное руководство",
              "author":1,
              "viewers":213
            }
        ],
    blogs_ajax:[]
  };

}


componentDidMount() {
    this.navItems();
}

async navItems() {
     //CHA - simulating a small gap in between the table initially loading and the data arriving.
    this.setState({blogs_ajax: this.state.blogs_ajax});
}

render() {

    console.log(this.state.blogs) // But I can see the result here

    return (

        <div id="content">

            <h1>React Table</h1>
            <Datatable
                options={{ data: this.state.blogs,
                           columns: [
                               {data: "title"},
                               {data: "author"},
                               {data: "viewers"},
                           ]
                        }} />
        </div>
    );
    }
}
```

Next is trimmed down example of your datatables wrapper from your repo.  look at the comments prefixed CHA.

```
import React from "react";
import $ from "jquery";

require("datatables.net-bs");
require("datatables.net-buttons-bs");
require("datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.js");
require("datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.js");
require("datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.js");
require("datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.js");
require("datatables.net-colreorder-bs");
require("datatables.net-responsive-bs");
require("datatables.net-select-bs");

export default class Datatable extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.datatable(this.props.data);

        console.log("CHA - In datables.js did mount - data will be undefined initially");
        console.log(this.props.data);
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){

        console.log("CHA - shouldcomponentupdate - we should now have data.");
        console.log(nextProps.options.data);
        console.log("CHA - because of the way you build the datatable, we need to rebuild instead of redraw.");
        this.datatable(nextProps.options.data);

        return true;
    }

    datatable() {
        const element = $(this.refs.table);
        let { options } = { ...this.props } || {};

        let toolbar = "";

        if (options.buttons) toolbar += "B";
        if (this.props.paginationLength) toolbar += "l";
        if (this.props.columnsHide) toolbar += "C";

        if (typeof options.ajax === "string") {
            let url = options.ajax;
            options.ajax = {
            url: url,
            complete: function(xhr) {
          // AjaxActions.contentLoaded(xhr)
        }
    };
}

options = {
  ...options,
  ...{
    dom:
      "<'dt-toolbar'<'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'f><'col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-xs text-right'" +
      toolbar +
      ">r>" +
      "t" +
      "<'dt-toolbar-footer'<'col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-xs'i><'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'p>>",
    oLanguage: {
      sSearch:
        "<span class='input-group-addon input-sm'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></i></span> ",
      sLengthMenu: "_MENU_"
    },
    autoWidth: false,
    retrieve: true,
    responsive: true
  }
};
console.log("before const call");
console.log(options);
const _dataTable = element.DataTable(options);

if (this.props.filter) {
  // Apply the filter
  element.on("keyup change", "thead th input[type=text]", function() {
    _dataTable
      .column(
        $(this)
          .parent()
          .index() + ":visible"
      )
      .search(this.value)
      .draw();
  });
}

if (!toolbar) {
  element
    .parent()
    .find(".dt-toolbar")
    .append(
      '<div class="text-right"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="SmartAdmin" style="width: 111px; margin-top: 3px; margin-right: 10px;"></div>'
    );
}

if (this.props.detailsFormat) {
  const format = this.props.detailsFormat;
  element.on("click", "td.details-control", function() {
    const tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    const row = _dataTable.row(tr);
    if (row.child.isShown()) {
      row.child.hide();
      tr.removeClass("shown");
    } else {
      row.child(format(row.data())).show();
      tr.addClass("shown");
    }
        });
    }
  }

    render() {
        let {
              children,
              options,
              detailsFormat,
              paginationLength,
              ...props
        } = this.props;

        console.log("CHA - In render");
        console.log(this.props);

        return (
            <table {...props} ref="table">
                {children}
            </table>
        );
    }
}
```